# Who is responsible for serialization/deserialization in ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, serialization, activemq-classic

Which side is responsible for classes serialization/deserialization in ActiveMQ when I'm using `ObjectMessage`?

I was assuming that the client, because the classes must be sent to server in serialized form, however I've observed that my queue was 'broken' by sending `ObjectMessage`: I receive null reading from that queue, even if I have reversed my conde changes and I send `TextMessage`, as previously. When I switch to another queue, everything works fine.

It looks like the instances of `ObjectMessage` were stuck on server side, but I see no errors in logs... Simply nothing can be read from queue...

Comment: The answers are below, but I suggest avoiding ObjectMessage unless you are messaging between instances of the same code base. You will have better control using text/bytes messages with json/xml/protobuf/whatnot.

Comment: Please refer this link http://activemq.apache.org/openwire.html

Answer (score 1):

ObjectMessage uses Java serialization to store the message as a byte payload in the transmitted protocol message.  This implies that the client on the sender and receiver need to have the class on their classpath so that it can be sent / received.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that none of the "usual" ActiveMQ storage providers (KahaDB, etc) require an ObjectMessage to be deserialized. The data is just stored raw. As a result, serialization and deserialization only (usually) happens on then clients.

Recent ActiveMQ clients are blocked from deserializing ObjectMessage at all, as a result of a CVE, unless they are explicitly whitelisted:

-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=com.acme

There's a API on the connection factory as well, but I have a feeling that it isn't implemented.

Note that "*" (all packages) is a legal value of SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES, but you have to be careful that the shell/command prompt doesn't accidentally expand it into a list of filenames.

The restriction on deserialization produces a clear exception so, if the problem is just that no messages are being consumed at all, with no errors or exceptions, probably the problem is elsewhere.